# WPSClient with raster input parameter

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm trying to run a WPS process on a GeoServer instance using OpenLayers [WPSClient](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/WPSClient-js.html). One of the parameters of the process is a raster layer. How do I pass this to using the WPSClient? 
 The [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/WPSClient-js.html) indicates how to call this with vector data, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with raster data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers does not have objects wrapping coverages, e.g. WCS, thus you'll have to do it some other way. The easiest might be to directly pass [the URL for a WCS resource](http://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html#test-your-wcs-1-0-server).